# Do I have to specify the indirect dependencies in the requires section of a package?

Tags: delphi, dependencies, package, delphi-10.1-berlin

Let's say I have these projects:

- Package1.bpl
- Package2.bpl (uses units in Package1)
- Package3.bpl (uses units in both Package1 and Package2)
- Package4.bpl (uses units in Package2 only)
- Project1.exe (uses units from all of the above)

What is the correct `requires` section for each of those?

Package2 clearly depends on Package1.

Package3 depends on both Package1 and Package2? Or is it ok to just specify Package2 if I know that Package2 will depend on Package1?

What about Package4 does it have to specify Package1 in addition to Package2?

What are the rules for what goes into the `requires` section of a package?

PS: Let's assume I want to be able use static linking as well as dynamic linking.

BTW: I tried running the bpls through [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), but then the actual imports and exports that Delphi generates under the hood are not in a 1:1 relation to the requisites anyway.

Comment: I don't remember ever having to do that.

Comment: If your Package3 is directly using some functionality from Package1 the said package should be added to requires section.

Comment: I see that the docwiki has some info on this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Deciding_Which_Runtime_Packages_to_Use

Comment: So it seems you only ever have to list the *direct* dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any package required by a required package is seen as indirectly required and need no own reference in the requires section.

Given your example above the requires for each package should at least contain

```
Package1: 
Package2: Package1
Package3: Package2 (makes Package1 indirectly required)
Package4: Package2 (makes Package1 indirectly required)
```

Of course each package should list all required standard (RTL, VCL,...) packages. The above rule can be applied for those, too. F.i. requiring vcl implicitly requires rtl.

Comment: Why should each package list the required standard packages? The docwiki even says that you can for example list `vlcx` and then don't need to list `rtl` and `vcl` anymore.

Comment: A bpl is really a dll, so when using runtime packages in an executable the packages are dynamically linked (dll = dynamic link library). Also there is delayed loading of dlls, but I think that does not work for runtime packages.

Comment: Replace dynamic linking with *explicit* dynamic linking and static linking with *implicit* *dynamic* linking, then I can agree with your last paragraph.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, of course the above rule holds true even for the standard packages. I see now that the phrasing is misleading. Regarding the linking phrasing I just took what I understood from the question and used the same wording to avoid confusion. I agree that the use of those words are not totally exact here.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff, can you clarify what you then mean by "I want to be able use static linking as well as dynamic linking"?

Comment: I want to be able to link my application with or without runtime packages (The project setting called "Link with runtime packages"). Effectively that means static (everything is pulled into the exe) or dynamic linking (bpls are needed to run the exe) of packages.

Comment: OK, I see. In that case I can remove my last paragraph. On the other side I cannot see why that should matter. You either compile with packages or not.

Comment: I added the part about runtime packages, because I thought it might matter. If it doesn't just ignore that part of the question.